# Seleccionar un registro aleatoriamente en MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Cómo puedo seleccionar de forma aleatoria un registro de una base de datos que cumpla una condición (es decir, que también sea posible usar el WHILE).

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mitabla WHERE cat=4 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

Ese ejemplo estaría bien?

Comment: Si tienes mysql sería como tu dices

Answer (score 0):

se podría aplicar un rand desde 1 a el valor máximo de id de todos los registros

ejemplo:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mitabla WHERE cat=4 and id=FLOOR(RAND()*((SELECT max(id) FROM mitabla WHERE cat=4)-1+1)+1) LIMIT 1");
```